# using require within a custom nodejs module

Tags: node.js

I'm struggling to understand why this basic code is not working.

If I write a custom module. It's in a folder called MonkeyContacts/ Inside the folder there are 3 js files and an index.js. My plan was to put 1 function per file and constants in another.

```
| MonkeyContacts

   |- ContactKeys.js

   |- ContactCOQL.js

   |- ContactQuery.js

   |- index.js
```

So in ContactKeys.js

```
const contactKeys = [5, 6, 7];
module.exports = contactKeys;
```

Then in ContactCOQL.js -

```
const monkeyContacts  = require(`./index.js`);
const {contactKeys}   = require(`../MonkeyContacts`);

const contactCOQL = (module, email) => {
    console.log(contactKeys)     // undefined
    console.log(monkeyContacts.contactKeys) // undefined
}
    
module.exports = contactCOQL;
```

And in the index.js, I have:

```
const contactCOQL     = require("./ContactCOQL");
const contactQuery    = require("./ContactQuery");
const contactKeys     = require("./ContactKeys");

module.exports = {
  contactCOQL,
  contactQuery,
  contactKeys,
};
```

I'm able to use these functions and whatnot from other modules,

```
const monkeyContacts = require('../../MonkeyContacts');
...
console.log(monkeyContacts.contactKeys);
```

but I can't figure out how to get the code in ContactCOQL.js to work where it tries to import contactKeys !? Sorry, I know this is basic.

Comment: You are messing everything up. Are you open to refactor using POO?

Comment: I'm open to improvement! Whaever form that takes.

Comment: `const {contactKeys}   = require('./ContactKeys');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ContactCOQL.js` file try the following. See what it gives in console. Don't use `.js` at the end of the file while using require. Also when in same directory, just use `./file_name` to require.

```
const contactKeys = require(`./ContactKeys");

const contactCOQL = (module, email) => {
    console.log(contactKeys);
}
    
module.exports = contactCOQL;
```